# "Eval Error" when selectively rendering raster layers in QGIS Atlas

Tags: qgis, raster, print-composer, atlas, rule-based

Using the Atlas feature in the QGIS print composer, it is possible to use rule-based symbology to show/hide components of vector layers as required or defined by the Atlas?

I have multiple pages, defined by a feature of a vector file ("Name"). I have raster layers in my project that contain "Name" in their respective layer names. Is it possible to create a rule to only render those layers that contain "Name" on the respective Atlas page?

The reason for this is that there is overlap between Atlas pages and the raster layers can sometimes overlap in unwanted ways. Below is an example where the page with "Name" = A is obfuscated by an unwanted raster layer, B. Ideally, only rasters containing A would be rendered.

[image]

I believe it should be able to be done using the Expression String Builder and possibly the Function editor from the Layers drop down in the Item Properties for the desired map in the print layout.

I have a function in my Function editor defined:

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def find_match_fun(str_to_match):
    names = [layer.name() for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()]
    names_match = [el for e in names for el in e.split() if el.startswith(str_to_match)]
    names_out = '|'.join(map(lambda x: "'" + x + "'", names_match))
    return(names_out)
```

However attempting to invoke that in the Expression string builder results in an error:

> find_match_fun("A")
>  Eval Error: find_match_fun() takes 1 positional
> argument but 3 were given

Calling the function from Python console in QGIS returns the expected list. I am unsure what I'm missing.

Comment: Not sure this fully answers your question, hence the comment but you should add `feature` and `parent` parameters to your custom function after your `str_to_match` parameter. Have a look at: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/custom_python_functions.html

Comment: Thanks that got me going down the right path. How should I mark this as complete?

Comment: Great! If this solved your problem I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not tested your function, but the `Eval Error` you are seeing is because QGIS custom functions take additional `feature` and `parent` parameters. This is explained in the help section of the function editor shown below:

[image]

And quoted directly here:

> Define a new function using the `@qgsfunction` decorator.
>
> The function accepts the following parameters
>
> : param [any]: Define any parameters you want to pass to your
> function before  the following arguments.
>   : param feature: The
> current feature
>   : param parent: The `QgsExpression` object
>   : param
> context: If there is an argument called `context` found at the last
> position, this variable will contain a `QgsExpressionContext`
> object, that gives access to various additional information like
> expression variables. E.g. `context.variable( 'layer_id' )`
>   : returns: The result of the expression.

Therefore, you should add `feature` and `parent` parameters to your custom function after your `str_to_match` parameter.

```py
...
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def find_match_fun(str_to_match, feature, parent):
...
```

You can also have a look at this helpful [tutorial](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/custom_python_functions.html):